# make a new php or temp file automatically to display more details

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm making an e-commerce website using php and now I have create a code for display posts in database on web page. But I want to make a new web page or tmp file automatically with a special name to display more details, images and contents when I click this post(div). How can I do this?

Thank You!

Comment: Well, your tags are on the right track. You can use those to make your site.

Comment: You are basically asking how to make a dynamic content web site. This question is far too broad. Suggest looking at how some of the php frameworks manage such issues

Answer (score 0):

When you render your posts in html, you can make `a` link which will guide user to script with full information about post.

You should create new php script for this case. For example `view.php`, which will get parameter, for example, `post_id`. And in this script you can get this parameter to fetch information about post from database